# Pandas: Determine if columns are matched

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to eliminate all rows that match in `col0` and `col1`, but don't have a pair of `-1, 1` between rows (for example in the dataframe below there isn't a `a2, b1, -1` row). I was trying to come up with someway to do this, but was `groupby` and getting multiindex and not getting anywhere...

```
#   no a2, b1, -1
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a1', 'b1', -1, 0/1],
    ['a1', 'b1',  1, 1/1],
    ['a1', 'b2', -1, 2/1],
    ['a1', 'b2',  1, 1/2],
    ['a2', 'b1',  1, 1/3],
    ['a2', 'b2', -1, 2/3],
    ['a2', 'b2',  1, 4/1]
], columns=['col0', 'col1', 'col2', 'val'])

# desired output
# a1, b1, -1, 0.0
# a1, b1,  1, 1.0
# a1, b2, -1, 2.0
# a1, b2,  1, 0.5
# a2, b2, -1, 0.66667
# a2, b2,  1, 4.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`groupby filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) to test if there are at least 1 ([`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html)) of each value (-1 and 1) per group with [`Series.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
result_df = df.groupby(['col0', 'col1']).filter(
    lambda x: x['col2'].eq(-1).any() and x['col2'].eq(1).any()
)
```

`result_df`:

```
  col0 col1  col2       val
0   a1   b1    -1  0.000000
1   a1   b1     1  1.000000
2   a1   b2    -1  2.000000
3   a1   b2     1  0.500000
5   a2   b2    -1  0.666667
6   a2   b2     1  4.000000
```

Comment: Only works if there is only 1 of each value in a group or if there are only even pairs. That is unclear from the question if these requirements will hold. [1, 1, -1] passes this filter but not sum (for example)

Answer (score 1):

If it is always supposed to be exactly one (-1, 1) pair in each group we could just sum:

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['col0', 'col1'])['col2'].transform('sum') == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution but you can use `df['col2'].abs()` to group rows:

```
>>> df[df.groupby(['col0', 'col1', df['col2'].abs()])['col2'] \
         .transform('count').eq(2)]

  col0 col1  col2       val
0   a1   b1    -1  0.000000
1   a1   b1     1  1.000000
2   a1   b2    -1  2.000000
3   a1   b2     1  0.500000
5   a2   b2    -1  0.666667
6   a2   b2     1  4.000000
```

**Another solution** (maybe better) using `pivot`:

```
>>> df.pivot(index=['col0', 'col1'], columns='col2', values='val') \
      .dropna(how='any').stack().rename('val').reset_index()

  col0 col1  col2       val
0   a1   b1    -1  0.000000
1   a1   b1     1  1.000000
2   a1   b2    -1  2.000000
3   a1   b2     1  0.500000
4   a2   b2    -1  0.666667
5   a2   b2     1  4.000000
```

Comment: I like the pivot approach. I don't know if there are duplicates allowed within groups. Both of these approaches will fail if there are duplicates of `1` or `-1` within a group.

Comment: @HenryEcker. That's what I meant by "not perfect" and "maybe better" :-)

Comment: Ah okay. I think these are good approaches and they work if the conditions are -1 or 1 only... I just don't know if that is always the case.

Comment: @Corralien - nice solution, but I actually have multiple columns, so pivoting is not an option